# How to convert array of uint8_t values to hex dump char string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, hex

I want to convert byte array `uint8_t` Hexadecimal values to char array string **(**same values not ASCII**) and then simple print this string array as below:

**input:**

```
uint8_t myarr[4]={0x11,0x12,0x33,0x1A}
```

**output:**

```
 1112331A
```

Simple char array string not hexadecimal array string.

Comment: What you are asking for is often called "hex dump", if I understand your question correctly. Google "hex dump c" or something to get examples. If you are having trouble with this, try to expand the question more with your own code, because a lot of things depends on what you actually want.

Comment: Short code to get your desired output: `for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) printf("%02X", myarr[i]);` . If you actually want a string, it gets a bit more complicated of course, because of how C does strings, and needs those extra details missing from the question.

Comment: What is a "hexadecimal array string"? A string always is a sequence of single characters that is terminated by a 0 byte.

Answer (score 6):

Just loop over the elements of the array and use `printf` to print each element using the `"%hhx"` format specifier.

Also note that the values will not be stored as hexadecimal. Hexadecimal is just a form to present values.

Comment: I was just gonna say `%hhx`. Nice.

Comment: Since this is not scanf, does the %hhx make any sense? The function will receive an int anyway (it's a variable arguments function), so %x or %02x should be ok. Do I miss something?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Yes, a *signed* `int` with possible *sign extension*.

Comment: The correct format string is actually `"%" PRIx8` from inttypes.h.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, my comment was missing `unsigned`. Since the original datum is a `uint8_t`, shouldn't it be promoted to an `unsigned int`? Example: https://ideone.com/1VlMGv and https://godbolt.org/z/qWIkCx.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana [Integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) says that "[i]f `int` can represent the entire range of values of the original type ..., the value is converted to type `int`". Since `int` can represent the entire range of values of an `unsigned char` (which `uint8_t` usually is) then the promoted value type will be `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The old school way of raw data to ASCII hex conversion, is to use a look-up table based on nibbles:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  uint8_t myarr[4]={0x11,0x12,0x33,0x1A};
  char hexstr[4][2+1] = {0};

  const char HEX [16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    hexstr[i][0] =  HEX[ (myarr[i] & 0xF0) >> 4 ];
    hexstr[i][1] =  HEX[ (myarr[i] & 0x0F) ];
    puts(hexstr[i]);
  }
}
```