# Convert Hexadecimal values of an array into String values of another array

Tags: c, string, char, hex, byte

I am trying to convert the hexadecimal values of an array into characters of another one. Here is the only way, I could find but not working.

Thank you for your help !

```
char tmp[] = {0x81, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12, 0x05};
char new[12];

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf(" %x", tmp[i]);
    sprintf(new + i, "%x", tmp[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf(" %c", new[i]);
}
printf("new: %s\n", new);
```

Here is the output :

```
 81 0 0 0 12 5
 8 0 0 0 1 5
new: 800015
```

So, it lacks some bytes ...

Comment: What do you mean "characters". The ASCII representation of hex values? But you only have 6 bytes so that won't fit. You are also using sprintf for writing into the same array as the target...

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: `sprintf(tmp + i, "%x", tmp[i]);` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You attempt to write a multi-character string into a single character. Not to mention that using `tmp[i]` as both an argument and as destination is also UB as per the C specification.

Comment: For binary to hex ASCII conversion, there are thousands of snippets already posted on the internet, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54129120/584518

Comment: Your edit doesn't change much: You're still writing a multi-character string into the single character `new[i]`. Also note that if `char` is signed (it may be signed or unsigned, it's an implementation (compiler) detail) then `0x81` would lead to *sign extension* as it's considered a negative value. Use `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>` for generic unsigned bytes. And please learn about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (which is the most common way to handle negative values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably

```
char tmp[] = {0x81, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12, 0x05};
char new[6];
```

must be

```
int tmp[] = {0x81, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12, 0x05};
char new[6*2+1];
```

and

```
sprintf(tmp + i, "%x", tmp[i]);
```

must be

```
sprintf(new + 2*i, "%02x", tmp[i]);
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf(" %c", new[i]);
}
```

must be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6*2; i++) {
        printf(" %c", new[i]);
}
```

Execution :

```
/tmp % ./a.out
 81 0 0 0 12 5 8 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 5new: 810000001205
```

Under *valgrind* :

```
/tmp % valgrind ./a.out
==15557== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15557== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15557== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15557== Command: ./a.out
==15557== 
 81 0 0 0 12 5 8 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 5new: 810000001205
==15557== 
==15557== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15557==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15557==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==15557== 
==15557== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15557== 
==15557== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15557== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: @user694733 you are right, I see after, I edited my answer

Comment: There's still IMO no reason to use such a cumbersome function as sprintf for something fairly trivial like this.

Comment: @Lundin lol I agree, I just corrected the errors from the original definition ^^

Comment: @Lundin How you do without sprintf ?

Comment: @GaelG I posted a link to a snippet as comment below your question.

Comment: @Lundin Okay thank you very much for your help. I am closing the ticket.